# Как называется по-русски распределение, плотность которого 1/x?

Tags: математика, терминология, численные-методы, теория-вероятностей

Ричард Хэмминг опубликовал в 1970 году статью ["On the Distribution of Numbers"](https://archive.org/stream/bstj49-8-1609). В этой статье он решил вопрос о том, как выглядит распределение мантисс всех представимых чисел в арифметике с плавающей точкой по основанию `b` (мантисса, это число в интервале [1/b;1] )

Решение выглядит очень просто - в пределе это распределение стремится к распределению с плотностью

```
r(x) = 1 / ( x ln b )
```

По-английски с лёгкой руки Хэмминга это распределение называется [Reciprocal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_distribution). Однако в учебниках на русском языке мне не удалось найти ничего об этом вероятностном распределении.

Математические словари предлагают перевод

```
reciprocal distribution => квантиль распределения
```

Этот перевод, как мне кажется, совсем не о том.

Как принято называть *reciprocal distribution* по-русски?

Comment: А чем вам не нравятся квантили? Нам на мат. статистике давали именно этот термин

Comment: квантили это немного о другом

Comment: @ViktorTomilov насколько я помню, квантиль, это функция обратная функции распределения. Т.е., если K - квантиль, F - функция распределения и `F(x) = a`, то `K(a) = x`. Квантиль определена для любого распределения, а тут - совершенно конкретное.

Comment: Тогда прошу прощения. Помню, что термин квантили давали и не раз, поэтому и не возмутился :)

Answer (score 1):

Инверсное распределение.

Сошлюсь на [статью в Википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution)

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ, не могли бы вы привести ссылку, где этот  термин применялся бы именно в этом контексте на русском языке? Поиск в вебе на слова "инверсное распределение" выдает мне исключительно статьи о лазерах и распределении частиц по энергетическим уровням.